# What pattern/technique do I use for a reactive MVC Razor interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

On a whim I wrote the UI for my latest desktop app as an MVC ASP application running on IIS.
It looks really nice.

The application has a button that starts a process that permanently reads a UDP port.  The I want the UI to become active and for data to be shown on the UI

In ASP this seem to be a lot more involved than the WinForms way of a background process and updating a form control.
I have considered polling from the UI but that doesn't feel right.

How do I return to the UI so I can (for example) press a stop button?
What technique should I use to push arriving data to the UI?

Comment: Research [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) a server-side software system designed for writing scalable Internet applications, notably web servers. Programs are written on the server side in C#, using event-driven, asynchronous I/O to minimize overhead and maximize scalability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [Learn About ASP.NET SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes
>   developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows
>   bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can
>   now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes
>   available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other
>   compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for
>   connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events),
>   grouping connections, and authorization.

Comment: I tried this and it's what I need for the Push part